# Pay Close Attention - A puzzle for all those who can think outside the box

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

Reclining in his chair, Watson wrapped his arms around himself in what could be conceived as a bear hug, had there been another person there. Waiting patiently, Watson hummed a small tune to himself and glanced idly to the ceiling. It was only a matter of time now.

Earnestly, a knock came to the door. Watson asked who was there, even though he already knew. The visitor was long expected.

Deliriously, the door creaked open, and welcomed a face that could not have been happier. Grinning ear from ear, the visitor practically skipped over to the desk and stuck out his hand.

"Here I am, old chap!" The visitor cried with delight. "It's been too long. To think, Watson, truest of friends, a private investigator!"

Errantly, the visitor began to chatter on about other things while Watson internalized his patience. He knew he was going to need it.

"...read that you were in this office, and that's how I found out you were here!" The visitor summed up. "I think you know the rest. So now, what's up with you? How have things been?"

Reposure settled over the room as the visitor beamed expectantly in Watson's silence. The visitor's excitement slowly began to ebb away as he began to notice Watson's sour expression.

Innately, the realization dawned on him. "What's the matter?" The visitor asked Watson, "Has it finally happened?"

Noting the change in manner, Watson eradicated the last of the visitor's bubbliness by tossing down a letter squarely onto the desk.

"Get it now?" Watson replied as the visitor read the note.

> You always complained about being second, didn't you, Watson? Look at me, I don't even get that! That which comes after the main character, whether a person or thing, is still more famous than me, Watson! Oh, how can that be?
>
> Is the side character more important than the main one, Watson? Can you really ever become that good, Watson? Killing you off is what I should have done, for now the great Watson steals the throne! I will amend that mistake, Watson, ending this ridicule of my name!
>
> You are all I here about now, Watson, nothing about me! Watson ends a villain's reign, Watson meets the queen! Well, I promise you this, Watson: Yesterday will be the last time you show up in the newspaper until your obituary!

"Such a malicious rant," the visitor finally said, "It's like a piece of bad poetry. Fortunately, given all that has happened today, I think someone can figure who wrote this." He continued.

*Who is threatening Watson?*

Comment: Wow! Somebody's a little jealous...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The initial letters of the words directly after the word "Watson" ("That which comes after the main character") spell out "WHAT IS SHERLOCKS ENEMY" - so I guess we're talking about Professor Moriarty, as usual.
>  I note and appreciate your RED HERRING on the paragraph starts.

Comment: Wow, nice job! I didn't think anyone would get it that fast.